# Azure Mobile Service required Authentication?

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, azure-sql-database

I created Azure Mobile Service with .Net backend, When i try for json response (like https://.azure-mobile.net/tables/) it asking Authentication(username & password), what details i need to provide.?

Answer (score 1):

in this article

[microsoft’s windows app studio beta: connecting a menu app to azure mobile service](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/microsoft-windows-app-studio-beta-connecting-a-menu-app-to-azure-mobile-service/) in "Running the Services> Server" you will see the information you need with images to help to find the keys you need from Azure Portal.

This article is related with the sample:

[Microsoft’s Windows App Studio Beta: Connecting a Menu App to Azure Mobile Service, BackOffice App, support for Push Notifications, Cortana and tips for submit the app in the Store.](https://github.com/AppStudioSamples/Menu)